# How do I fix a freezer door that's hard to open soon after closing it?

Tags: refrigerator, freezer

I notice that my freezer door is really hard to open soon after I close it. I'm pretty sure I know why this is happening -- warm (and thus lower density) air is being let in. When I close the door, the volume of the air reduces as it cools down, thus causing a lower pressure inside the fridge than the outside.

How do I fix this issue?

I'm fairly sure the fridge is not properly functioning for two reasons:

1. The door is incredibly hard to open. I'd estimate I have to apply 80 lbs of force or more to open it. Sometimes I'm simply not strong enough to open it and just need to wait 5 minutes or so to make it easier to open.
2. This wasn't a problem when I first bought this fridge. I think only after about a year did this problem start happening.

Comment: Can someone help me understand how this question needs to be clarified?

Answer (score 7):

The fact that your freezer vacuum-seals itself closed is a good thing. It is a sign that the seals are functioning well. If the seals were not functioning well then there would be a continuous path for ambient humidity of the room to get into the freezer where it will cause accelerated frost buildup on the evaporator coils, and that in turn reduces efficiency and increases energy consumption.

With that perspective, maybe we could re-frame the question like "how can I more easily open the freezer door shortly after it was closed?"

An answer to that would be to use your finger tips or nails to lift the gasket away from the sealing surface. That's an easy way to break the vacuum, and then the door will open as easily as it does after sitting closed for a long period.

Comment: In fact, some freezer door opening mechanisms are designed to lift the seal from a section to enable the door to open easily.

Comment: That's a good point about the humidity. Unfortunately breaking the seal in my case doesn't work too well, though maybe I'm a more specialized case than I thought. The gasket is simply not reachable -- the fridge is inset into the cabinet. The gap between the cabinet and fridge is about a centimeter, so I can't even touch the gasket without opening the freezer.

I understand my solution is odd, but I have yet to find another solution that works.

Comment: I've also clarified the question as to why I'm using the word "fix"

Comment: @theicfire With some searching I found that some refrigerators are actually equipped with a vacuum breaker device. Maybe yours is one of them and the device has failed. Or, maybe you could obtain the replacement part from another model (or craft your own) and retrofit it to your freezer. Seems like a device could relieve vacuum inside the appliance, but then close automatically by a spring or gravity to prevent air leakage or humidity problems.

Comment: I've been looking for such a device but couldn't find it! Can you share links? This is the best I found: https://www.geapplianceparts.com/store/parts/spec/WR01X29412 (but nothing for any other fridges). I'm also curious by what the word "drain" means in this context. Water drain when melting? Ice tray drain? I even called Samsung and they didn't know (though it was just a random support person on the phone).

Answer (score -1):

From what I understand, this typically isn't a problem because freezers have slight leaks in them (say, around the door gasket). One quick solution you could try is to add a small leak -- I did this by taping a tooth pick on the fridge where the gasket touches. This small added leak will help equalize the pressure.

I'd recommend putting the toothpick at the top of the fridge, because cold air is denser and thus won't escape upwards as readily as it will escape downwards.

I'm guessing this has hardly any impact on the efficiency of the freezer. The gap is so small that when I close the freezer, I can actually hear the air from outside rushing in over the span of about 10 seconds before the fridge equalizes. If the gap were large, this rushing in of air would be much quicker.

Comment: "I'm guessing this is hardly an impact" no reason to guess, easy to test.

Comment: The problem with this solution is that you've created a long-term gap in your freezer seal requiring the freezer compressor to run more often to maintain the same internal temperature in order to solve a very short-term issue of it being somewhat more difficult to open during a short period after you've closed it. Apparently, you close then reopen the door often enough for this to be an issue for you, but it really seems like a non-issue compared to letting warm air into the freezer for the other 23.5 hours/day that you're not opening/closing the door constantly.

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateUkraine, please elighten us. How would one scientifically measure efficiency of an appliance (without specialized equipment)?

Comment: Run it for a week on a Kill-a-Watt in similar ambient temps. @isherwood. The Kill-a-Watt reads out "hours since plugged in" and "watt-hours since plugged in".  Divide one by the other.

Comment: So... specialized equipment. Also, usage must be very consistent across the test. (I did say "scientific", which is the only useful method.)

Comment: Settle down, now. We're all scientists here.

Comment: i was going to suggest a small strip of stick on velcro - loop side to break the vacuum as it's removable without leaving a mark or indentation.